# Windows Clipboard, Store Image Using MS Forms Data Object - VBA

Tags: windows, vba

I want to put an image on the Windows clipboard using VBA. I currently do this for text essentially as described [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/clipboard.aspx) using the DataObject in the MS Forms 2.0 Library.

I want to do the same thing using an image file, putting the image on the clipboard instead of text.

My working code used for text is below, I have tried using the image file path as the variable but just stores the text. Also tried "SetImage" as a method but throws error as below.

```
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

DataObj.SetText str1   <--------------- works for string variable
DataObj.SetImage strImageFilePath <----------- Error Method not available

DataObj.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: You can't really just make up methods. The DataObject doesn't cope with images (it doesn't even cope with text very well in Win 8 or later). What are you planning to do with the image?

Comment: I want to manually paste the image into a non-msft application. The link I provided seems to indicate that images can be put on the clipboard.

Comment: You can load the image into a shape (~0,~0 dimension), and do the following `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap`

Comment: The first line from Chip's page: "The MSForms library contains an object called the DataObject that provides support for working with **text strings** on the Windows clipboard" (emphasis added). Of course the clipboard can hold images, but the `DataObject` is **not** the clipboard.

Comment: Yes, I have read again and see you are correct. I will look for a work around, thanks